# Pandas datafile: NaN values: only on the last rows of a large file, no data issue

Tags: python, excel, pandas

My Excel files has 7947 rows and 29 columns. I load it in Pandas datafile and clean the data of some colums. This works fine if I split the file in 2 parts, each part will run without issues. But if I run the file as a whole I get this as output and error: Why?

```
Open de Excel file InputPerSchoolActief.xlsx
sheet parsed
VESTIGINGSNAAM               object
INSTELLINGSNAAM_VESTIGING    object
dtype: object
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Wouter\OneDrive\Documents\MyPythonScripts\AC\ACMaakPaginaPerPOSchool.py", line 82, in <module>
    df['VESTIGINGSNAAM'] = df.VESTIGINGSNAAM.apply(clean_data)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 2220, in apply
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
  File "pandas\src\inference.pyx", line 1088, in pandas.lib.map_infer (pandas\lib.c:63043)
  File "C:\Users\Wouter\OneDrive\Documents\MyPythonScripts\AC\ACMaakPaginaPerPOSchool.py", line 35, in clean_data
    s = ''.join([i for i in s if i not in punct])
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

This is my code:

```
# punct = set(string.punctuation)
punct = {'>', '%', '/', '*', '^', '"', ',', ':', '+', '!', '.', '#', '@', ')', '(', ']', '|', '~', '$', ';', '=', '?', '[', '&', '\\', '}', '`', '{', "'", '_', '<'}

def clean_data(s): # remove punctuation & capitalize
    s = ''.join([i for i in s if i not in punct])
    s = s.capitalize()
    return s

# Import the excel file and call it xls_file
inputFileName = ('InputPerSchoolActief8-12.xlsx')
print ('Open de Excel file %s' % inputFileName)
xls_file = pd.ExcelFile(inputFileName)
df = xls_file.parse('Sheet1')
print ('sheet parsed')
print(df.dtypes)

time.sleep(30) # to make a printscreen of TaskManager when the dataframe is loaded but error does not occur yet

df['VESTIGINGSNAAM'] = df.VESTIGINGSNAAM.apply(clean_data)
```

FYI The data should be fine, it processes in 2 iterations. So I was thinking about a memory issue but the 2 print screens from my Windows Task manager suggest that this is not the cause?: 1 = during the sleep, 2 is right after the TypeError was raised...

Note when I run a half size Excel sheet:

```
print(df.dtypes)
```

returns column names with datatype -> VESTIGINGSNAAM = object:

```
SOORT PRIMAIR ONDERWIJS                        object
PROVINCIE                                      object
BEVOEGD GEZAG NUMMER                            int64
BRINNUMMER                                     object
VESTIGINGSNUMMER                               object
VESTIGINGSNAAM                                 object
```

... many more columns

But if I run the full Excel sheet is only returns:

```
VESTIGINGSNAAM               object
INSTELLINGSNAAM_VESTIGING    object
dtype: object
type: df[]
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
Traceback (most recent call last): (rest as above)
```

I.e. the script does not return the full datafile but it does continue to run to the next lines -> you can see so because I added:

```
print('type: df[]')
print (type(df['VESTIGINGSNAAM']))
```

which is still returned and then it fails in the line:

```
df['VESTIGINGSNAAM'] = df.VESTIGINGSNAAM.apply(clean_data)
```

as confirmed by the error reference to

```
line 89, in <module>
    df['VESTIGINGSNAAM'] = df.VESTIGINGSNAAM.apply(clean_data)
```

PS thanks to the comment of Ivan I have now added the logging.debug(df['VESTIGINGSNAAM']) which gives the following output:

```
DEBUG:root:0              Openbare Basisschool 't Eenspan
1       Openbare Basisschool 2 Emmen Mr Vegter
2              Openbare Basisschool De Esdoorn
3               Openbare Basisschool Emmermeer
4                Openbare Basisschool Angelslo
5                               De Hasselbraam
....(manual cut -> more rows)
28            Openbare Basisschool De Lindehof
29            Openbare Basisschool De Hekakker
                     ...                  
7916                                       NaN
7917                                       NaN
....(manual cut -> more rows)
7943                                       NaN
7944                                       NaN
7945                                       NaN
Name: VESTIGINGSNAAM, dtype: object
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

So the NaNs are the cause of the error. However, the Excel column has values in these rows. They do not show as NaN if I process a smaller file. So why does this happen?

[image: PC task manager on processing large Excel file]

Comment: is every entry in the file is a string ? s should be a string. The error means you are trying to iterate over a float. In short s is a float

Comment: Thanks. But why is the float no issue if I use the same script & same data but limited to half of the file? -> FYI "print (type(df['VESTIGINGSNAAM']))" returns "<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>". -> later in the script I iterate over each row of the datafile, retrieving and am able to perform string actions without issues, e.g. "vestigingsNaam = vestigingsNaam.title()". Also, I now notice that the "print(df.dtypes)" does not return the full result when processing the full file but it does with a smaller file... I updated my question with this information! Thx.

Comment: add debug printing of `s` before the offending line then guess where the values printed are coming from

Comment: thanks ivan, I have added the result as input to my question. Not sure if this is what you meant and also not sure how I can use this extra info to my benefit? :)

Comment: In Excel what were the values that converted to NaNs in Python? It seems, NaNs are at the end, find where the row they begin and check the row just before that one. Are there any special chars, misalignments (data somehow shifted, missing cells, etc.), even encoding items like accents? Even widen each cell to see if there are other lines/values.

Comment: Thanks Parfait. I have done a test and copied the data from the rows 2-4000 in Excel to the rows >4000. Still the issue occurs, i.e. NaN values. Also the data >4000 processes fine if it is part of a smaller file. So the issue seems to be the size of the table (dataframe) rather than the data itself...

Comment: Very interesting. If only we could see data to reproduce issue. It may be an OS issue.

Comment: It is actually 'open data' that I am working so I can share it. You can download the Excel file that causes the NaN values issue [here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlNIYisf3zAHiL4NdAAYbBmo1ZHeRQ).